# reading from a file . C

Tags: c, file, char, symbols, fgetc

I want to read this symbols with `fgetc()` ( I cant copy it, here [link to file.txt](http://rghost.ru/private/7RjyXXQrF/357e714760d1aca78257b08c16a225ba) )

This file is 2-byte long and its binary dump is `1A 98`.

`fgetc()` cant read it and return `-1`. Please help((

```
for (int k = 0; k < fileSize; k++)
{
    buffer[k] = (unsigned char) fgetc(f);
}
```

Picture of this symbols:
[image: Picture of this symbols]

Maybe something with character encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains `0x1A`, which means EOF and reading it will stop reading when the file is opened in text mode.

Try opening your file in binary mode.

Here is a test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *fileName = "codeText.txt";
    FILE* fp;
    int input;

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp==NULL) return 1;
    puts("text mode:");
    while((input = getc(fp)) != EOF) printf("%02X\n", (unsigned int)input);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) return 1;
    puts("binary mode:");
    while((input = getc(fp)) != EOF) printf("%02X\n", (unsigned int)input);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why this symbols means EOF?

Comment: @tproger The symbol only means EOF with ASCII text files.  Your files in not ASCII.  The above good answer reads and prints until End-of-File (EOF).